# ASP.NET SignalR - Consumed Bandwith while idle

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, signalr

Right now we are evaluating SignalR for an upcoming project. 
We want to use the "always on" features of SignalR to have the online status of connect C# clients. Having the status and pushing some IDs from the server to the clients from time to time is the main work the SignalR channel will do.

As far as I researched, SignalR will do great for this purpose since we don't plan to use the channel for heavy data transfer like those stock examples.

But there is one part I can't find any information on:

How much traffic does an idle SignalR (WebSocket) channel produce? 
In production we will have about 10.000 clients connected to one server (mainly internal corporate network). Is there a rule of thumb like "every client produces about 10kbps traffic for while idle"? 
In my lab Environment with 3-4 clients I was not able to create measureable traffic.

Any hints from production environments would be great.

Comment: Cannot you use a tool such as Wireshark to capture packets for a while and then measure bandwidth usage?

Comment: The problem is that - with only a few connected clients - the traffic seems to be to low to be measured. But I fear that it will grown exponential with more clients.

Comment: a thorough analysis of the captured packets will reveal the pattern of SignalR, which you can go back to its configuration and source code to confirm. Then you should have less concerns.

Answer (score 7):

When using the WebSockets and ServerSentEvents transport the server sends a KeepAlive message every 10 seconds. The keep alive message is just `{}` which is 2 bytes using UTF8 encoding. All other traffic is initiated either by the server or the client.